# iterate through temp table data in batches of 10k

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have approx 6 million entries in my temp table for which I want to perform update in one of my table in batches of 10k

eg:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data
(
    IDT INT IDENTITY
    ,ID INT
    ,processed int
)
```

Here I then insert 6.4 million IDs in `#Data`

Then I apply while loop as below

```
WHILE @Counter < = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #Data)
begin

--perform update in my main table on basis of ID

SET @Counter = @Counter + 1

end
```

This is taking huge time so I want to perform update in batches of 10k

Comment: Please avoid using *lacs* as a unit. It's not well understood outside the subcontinent.

Comment: can you show us the update ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it all in one statement?  I'm not sure what your `update` statement is, but here is an example:

```
update m
    set col = d.processed
    from maintable m join
         #data d
         on m.id = d.idt;
```